# Is there a superfast way to transform data frame rows to list elements?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply, rcpp

Suppose a data frame like this:

```
> n <- 3
> a <- data.frame(x=1:n,y=sample(letters,n,replace = T),stringsAsFactors = F)
> rownames(a) <- paste0("p",1:n)
> a
   x y
p1 1 a
p2 2 e
p3 3 b
```

I want to transform the data frame to a list like this:

```
$p1
$p1$x
[1] 1

$p1$y
[1] "a"


$p2
$p2$x
[1] 2

$p2$y
[1] "e"


$p3
$p3$x
[1] 3

$p3$y
[1] "b"
```

One intuitive ways to perform such transformation is to use `lapply` to iterate over all rows, but it is really slow. If it were a matrix, another way is `apply(a,1,as.list)`. I do some benchmark tests and they show that `apply` approach is 5 times fasters than `lapply` approach. Further more, I also tested `apply(a,1,as.vector,mode="list")` approach and it's 4 times faster than `as.list` approach. Unfortunately, it is a data frame with heterogeneous types of columns.

When the number of rows of the data frame is larger, all methods seem to work slowly. Is there a way to do this even faster? (Use Rcpp? and how?)

Comment: Can solution have different/no names in the list? Do you really want to coerce `x` values to characters? PS: Why do you want this list structure? A data.frame is a more natural structure for this data.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, they should be numeric!

Comment: `split(a,rownames(a))` would be another option.

Comment: What I really want to do is perform list-member-based mapping. For example, like mapping each row of settings to a `lm` model or `S4` object.

Comment: @thelatemail, it really works but `split` does not preserve the order of the original data frame since it sorts by row names as character.

Comment: Can you please show an example of what you actually want to do? Possibly you don't need this step.

Comment: Anything you do which involves creating a `structure` with that many elements each of which is a structure with many elements is going to be slow. There's just too much overhead involved in creating all the components.  Stick with a `data.frame` and modify whatever code you use to extract records.

Comment: I'm confused.  You've pretty much answered your own question with some of the best methods.

Comment: OK, @Roland. What I'm basically trying to do is build an interface between relational database and non-relational data processing. For example, suppose I have a data frame like `data.frame(name=c("Ken","Ashley"),type=c("A","B"),score=c(9,8))` but I want to create a non-relational database from it with each record adds some interests likeKen:reading,music;Ashley:dancing,swimming. The result should be like `list(list(name="Ken",type="A",score=9,interests=c("reading","music")),list(name="Ashley",type="B",score=8,interests=c("dancing","swimming"))`. It's what my package `rlist` is trying to do.

Comment: The fastest way I can get is to use `do.call(Map,c(function(...) {
`names<-`(list(...),cols)},a))` and set its names to the row names of `a`. The performance is much greater than all previous approaches.

Comment: For 300,000 rows data frame, here's the benchmark:
Unit: seconds
lapply: 25.8 s
split: 27.8 s
map: 1.3 s

Comment: For matrix, map approach is still the fastest, faster than `apply(a,1,as.vector,mode="list")` approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record (and since you've mentioned "Rcpp"), I'm adding an approach at the C level. The speedup is about 7x; there could be better / faster solutions, but -agreeing with the comments- it may be more suitable to plan a different approach than trying to make a specific part as fast as it gets especially if it's hard to get significant speedups.

```
library(inline)

ff <- cfunction(sig = c(R_df = "data.frame"), body = '
    R_len_t nr = LENGTH(VECTOR_ELT(R_df, 0)), nc = LENGTH(R_df);

    SEXP ans;
    PROTECT(ans = allocVector(VECSXP, nr));
    for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
        SET_VECTOR_ELT(ans, i, allocVector(VECSXP, nc));
        setAttrib(VECTOR_ELT(ans, i), R_NamesSymbol, 
                  getAttrib(R_df, R_NamesSymbol));
    }
    setAttrib(ans, R_NamesSymbol, getAttrib(R_df, R_RowNamesSymbol)); 

    for(int i = 0; i < nc; i++) {
        SEXP tmp;
        PROTECT(tmp = coerceVector(VECTOR_ELT(R_df, i), 
                                   TYPEOF(VECTOR_ELT(R_df, i))));
        switch(TYPEOF(tmp)) {
            case LGLSXP:
            case INTSXP: {
                R_len_t *ptmp = INTEGER(tmp);
                for(int j = 0; j < nr; j++) 
                    SET_VECTOR_ELT(VECTOR_ELT(ans, j), i, 
                                   ScalarInteger(ptmp[j]));
                break;              
            }
            case REALSXP: {
                double *ptmp = REAL(tmp);
                for(int j = 0; j < nr; j++) 
                    SET_VECTOR_ELT(VECTOR_ELT(ans, j), i, 
                                   ScalarReal(ptmp[j]));
                break;              
            }
            case STRSXP: {
                for(int j = 0; j < nr; j++) 
                    SET_VECTOR_ELT(VECTOR_ELT(ans, j), i, 
                                   ScalarString(STRING_ELT(tmp, j)));
                break;              
            }
        }
        UNPROTECT(1);
    }

    UNPROTECT(1);
    return(ans);
')

ff(a) 
#$p1
#$p1$x
#[1] 1
#
#$p1$y
#[1] "k"
#
#
#$p2
#$p2$x
#[1] 2
#
#$p2$y
#[1] "o"
#
#
#$p3
#$p3$x
#[1] 3
#
#$p3$y
#[1] "l"
```

And comparing with the approach of yours (mentioned in the comments) that proved to be fast:

```
identical(setNames(do.call(Map, 
                           c(function(...) 
                                "names<-"(list(...), colnames(a)), a)), 
                   row.names(a)), 
           ff(a))
#[1] TRUE
```

And on a larger "data.frame":

```
set.seed(101)
DF = do.call(cbind.data.frame, 
             replicate(4, cbind.data.frame(x = I(sample(letters, 1e5, T)), 
                                           y = runif(1e5), 
                                           z = sample(1e5)), simplify = F))
names(DF) = make.unique(names(DF), "")


identical(setNames(do.call(Map, 
                           c(function(...) 
                               "names<-"(list(...), colnames(DF)), DF)), 
                   row.names(DF)), 
          ff(DF))   
#[1] TRUE
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ans1 = setNames(do.call(Map, 
                                       c(function(...) 
                                           "names<-"(list(...), colnames(DF)), 
                                         DF)), 
                               row.names(DF)), 
               ff(DF), 
               times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr       min        lq    median       uq       max neval
#   ans1 3504.1825 3862.4333 3931.0853 4063.691 4162.9370    10
# ff(DF)  143.0398  340.6897  365.5144  404.475  498.3854    10
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the rows split into a list and then within each of these split the rows into a list with all the elements.  Here's an approach that matches the OP's output but I think @Roland's is more useful.  The use of `sprintf` is to address reordering done by `split`.  This has the advantage over the `apply(a, 1, as.list)` solution in that the individual elements of the nested lists are numeric and character whereas `apply` coerces everything to character (it forms a `matrix`).

```
rows <- 1:nrow(a)
breaks <- paste0("p", sprintf(paste0("%0", nchar(max(rows)), "d"), rows))
lapply(split(a, breaks), as.list)

## $p1
## $p1$x
## [1] 1
## 
## $p1$y
## [1] "g"
## 
## 
## $p2
## $p2$x
## [1] 2
## 
## $p2$y
## [1] "c"
## 
## 
## $p3
## $p3$x
## [1] 3
## 
## $p3$y
## [1] "t"
```

Answer (score -1):

From your comments I'd suggest to either use a real database or to use package data.table:

```
DT <- data.table(name=c("Ken","Ashley"),type=c("A","B"),score=c(9,8)) 
setkey(DT, name)
interests <- data.table(name=c("Ken", "Ashley"), 
               interests=list(c("reading","music"), c("dancing","swimming")))

DT[interests]
#     name type score        interests
#1:    Ken    A     9    reading,music
#2: Ashley    B     8 dancing,swimming
```

Note that at its core this is a list:

```
unclass(DT[interests])
$name
[1] "Ken"    "Ashley"

$type
[1] "A" "B"

$score
[1] 9 8

$interests
$interests[[1]]
[1] "reading" "music"  

$interests[[2]]
[1] "dancing"  "swimming"


attr(,"row.names")
[1] 1 2
attr(,".internal.selfref")
<pointer: 0x7fc7c4007978>
```